# Assigning tagfield value to a structure while using union

Tags: c, struct, unions

I'm trying to study c language using "Fundamentals of Data Structures in C" by Horowitz, Sahni, and Anderson-Freed. In the part about structures and unions, there's an exercise problem where I have to create a struct which includes union to include additional information depending on each struct's value.

The code is as follows:

```
/*
Modify the humanBeing structure so that we can include different information
based on marital status. Marital status should be an enumberated type with field
single, married, widowed, divorced. Use a union to include different information
based on marital status as follows:
- single. no information needed.
- married. include a marriage date field.
- widowed. include marriage date and death of spouse date fields.
- divorced. include divorce date and number of divorces fields.

Assign values to the fields for some person fo type humanBeing.
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct date {
    int year;
    int month;
    int date;
};

typedef struct wInfo {
    date dMarriage;
    date dDeath;
};

typedef struct dInfo {
    date dDivorce;
    int nDivorce;
};

typedef struct mType {
    enum tagField { single, married, widowed, divorced } maritalStatus;
    union {
        date dMarriage;
        wInfo death;
        dInfo divorce;
    } u;
};

typedef struct humanBeing {
    char name[10];
    int age;
    float salary;
    mType maritalInfo;
};

void main() {
    humanBeing person1;

    strcpy(person1.name, "Phil");
    person1.age = 20;
    person1.salary = 4800;
    person1.maritalInfo.maritalStatus = married;
    person1.maritalInfo.u.dMarriage.year = 1991;
    person1.maritalInfo.u.dMarriage.month = 6;
    person1.maritalInfo.u.dMarriage.date = 10;
}
```

My error occurs at:

```
person1.maritalInfo.maritalStatus = married;
```

The "married" has an error which reads: identifier "married" is unidentified.

But didn't I identify it when creating mType?

I found a solution to all the problems in the textbook online. I compared my code to the solutions. I couldn't see what I was doing differently, so I copied and pasted the solution's code onto my visual studio, but the same error occurs. This make me think maybe there's something wrong with my visual studio settings. But the error clearly states that it's a syntax error?

I'm sure that I'm making a silly mistake, but could you guys help out?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming C not C++ which you are probably using with VS:

Also those `typedef`s are useless, as they aren't `typedef`'ing anything.

Make them define a type by doing:

```
typedef struct mType {
  enum tagField { single, married, widowed, divorced } maritalStatus;
  union {
    date dMarriage;
    wInfo death;
    dInfo divorce;
  } u;
} mType;
```

Also do so for all those other `typedef`s as well.

---

Also `main()` is defined to return `int`, so it has to be

```
int main(void);
```

at least.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have changed my main to `int main(void)`. But I thought the name of the structure goes either before the brackets or after, not both. Am I wrong? I changed the code according to your advice, but the same error remains :(